# IntelliJ: Android resource value got stuck (cached?)

Tags: android, caching, intellij-idea

I have a value stuck in /res/colors.xml.

Changing the value won't reflect when I run.
Refactoring the color name DOES make the new value work.

Tried clearing the bin and gen folders, "Build > Rebuild project" and "File > Invalidate caches" but the problem persists.

Comment: I have the same problem with Strings in the resources, Did you ever solved it ?